# Add rows as columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to change my dataset by making all the rows into columns in pandas.

1. 5  6  7
2. 8  9  10

Needs to be changed as

1. 5  6  7  8  9  10

with different headers of course, any suggestions??

Comment: try using the reshape function from numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame([df.values.flatten()])` as follows:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   0  1   2
0  5  6   7
1  8  9  10

In [19]: pd.DataFrame([df.values.flatten()])
Out[19]:
   0  1  2  3  4   5
0  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

**Explanation:**

`df.values` returns `numpy.ndarray`:

```
In [18]: df.values
Out[18]:
array([[ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10]], dtype=int64)

In [19]: type(df.values)
Out[19]: numpy.ndarray
```

and numpy arrays have `.flatten()` method:

```
In [20]: df.values.flatten?
Docstring:
a.flatten(order='C')

Return a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.

In [21]: df.values.flatten()
Out[21]: array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int64)
```

`Pandas.DataFrame` constructor expects lists/arrays of rows:

If we try this:

```
In [22]: pd.DataFrame([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
Out[22]:
    0
0   5
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5  10
```

Pandas thinks that it's a list of rows, where each row has one element.

So i've enclosed that array into square brackets:

```
In [23]: pd.DataFrame([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
Out[23]:
   0  1  2  3  4   5
0  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

which will be understood as one row with 6 columns.

Comment: Could you please add a description with your answer?

Comment: Thanks but Alireza posted the same.

Comment: @BrandonA, i've added an explanation - i hope it got better now

Comment: @achaud, that's true, but i gave my answer 11 seconds earlier, so i couldn't know that Alireza Sohofi would give the same answer beforehand ;-)

Comment: @MaxU yes that is much better now!

Answer (score 1):

or just in one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df.values.flatten()
#out: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your flatten method and converting it back to pandas dataframe just did my work.

Comment: You're  very welcome, if the answer helped, I would appreciate if you consider "accepting" it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the reshape function from numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6, 7],[8, 9, 10]])
nparray = np.array(df.iloc[:,:])
x = np.reshape(nparray, -1)
df = pd.DataFrame(x) #to convert back to a dataframe
```

Comment: how do i convert it back to pandas data frame?

Comment: Just call the DataFrame() function. See the edition.

Comment: Thank you. I believe flatten method is a little easier than the reshape method for my data. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use reduce()

```
from import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6, 7],[8, 9, 10]])

df = pd.DataFrame([reduce(lambda x,y: list(x[1]) + list(y[1]), df.iterrows())])

df

   0  1  2  3   4   5
0  5  6  7  8   9  10
```